# Count in an Array a number of same value Items in Razor , Umbraco

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, umbraco

i am having an array of records

```
Model.Categories = ["apple", "banana", "apple", "orange"]
```

from this array i am displaying the records one by one

```
 @foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
            {
                <a href="@Url.ArticulateCategoryUrl(Model, category)">@category</a>                   
            }
```

so this currently displaying two times apple record but i wants to display single time with the count beside like this

```
apple -(2)
banana
orange
```

like this can any help me with this on Razor how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, we need to create Method in Model which will return a Dictionary of category and its occurrence. Please find the below method which can be used to return the dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<string,int> CountArray()
    {
        Dictionary<string, int> countArr = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (var category in Categories)
        {
            if(countArr.ContainsKey(category))
            {
                countArr[category] = countArr[category] + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                countArr[category] = 1;
            }
        }
        return countArr;
    }
```

Now create a variable in cshtml file and assign this value returning from model.
Use this variable in foreach loop.
I guess this will help you in resolving your problem.

I really don't suggest this approach. But as you need help please find the Razor Code.

```
@{ Dictionary<string, int> countarry = new Dictionary<string, int>();}
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories)
{
    if (countarry.ContainsKey(category))
    {
        countarry[category] = countarry[category] + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        countarry[category] = 1;
    }
}
@foreach (var categoryName in countarry.Keys)
            {
if(countarry[categoryName] > 1)
        <a href="@Url.ArticulateCategoryUrl(Model, categoryName)">@categoryName - (@countarry[categoryName])</a>
else
<a href="@Url.ArticulateCategoryUrl(Model, categoryName)">@categoryName</a>
    }
```

I hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: I got it. But ideally we shouldn't write more code in razor file. This is kind of business logic should reside in Model. Why do we need to write this code in Razor. Do we have specific requirement to do so?

Comment: hi i have  never used Model before in Umbraco so only i am lookin gin Razor

Comment: @GayathriMohan I have updated my answer for razor code. check once and let me know

Comment: hi thank you for the razor code but howerver the result displaying , apple(1), banana(1), apple(1), orange(1) , like this insteaded apple(2)

Comment: we can add if condition for count. Can you tell me if your value if greater than one then only u need can you clarify then we can update it based on that

Comment: hi , the values can be 1 or more , you are correct more then one we can show the count

Comment: What I mean, if count is 1 then we need to display only category otherwise category with count is that correct?

Comment: My Code looks fine. It should work. We are using dictionary how is it possible that it is having apple category twice. Can you recheck your code once and then debug if possibel. I have updated my answer for count condition.

Comment: hi , as i sad the count not increasing it keeps showing (1) , it should be  (2) for apple

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172652/discussion-between-gayathri-mohan-and-trinadh).

Answer (score 0):

I have simple solution

```
var fruits = ["apple","coconut","apple","banana","papaya"];
```

var sortFruits = [];
for(fruit of fruits ){

```
if(sortFruits.includes(fruit)==false){
    sortFruits.push(fruit);
}
```

}
console.log(sortFruits);

Comment: hi am looking in Razor

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it could be "Razor code" as you call, but why don't you use Linq GroupBy?

The following code produce your expected output on browser.

```
@foreach (var category in categories.GroupBy(k => k))
{
    <a>@category.Key@(category.Count() > 1 ? $" - ({category.Count()})" : "")</a><br/>
}
```

Example above works in Razor 3.0.0.0 and .Net franework 4.6.1 (C# 6.0)

The code above is a result after trying to output as expected in the question. If making it simpler, possibly it could work in earlier versions.

```
@foreach (var category in categories.GroupBy(k => k))
{
    <a>@category.Key - @category.Count()</a><br/>
}
```

Comment: hi it is not displaying count in your answer

Comment: there is $ symbol throws errro after removed also it doenst display count

Comment: $ is used for c# string interpolation. Don't just remove $. Replace this $" - ({category.Count()})"   with (@category.count()). This should work

Comment: oh, it didn't work in your environment? that could be because of difference in version of Razor and/or .Net framework. Whitch version is your target?

Comment: in my case, Razor is 3.0.0.0 and target framework is .Net franework 4.6.1 (C# 6.0)

Comment: I added simpler code in my answer. hope it can work in earlier versions.